# Using Navigation Drawer for displaying a list of events

Tags: mobile, lists, maps

So I'm working on a mobile app that deals with events and I'm looking into ways to display available events in an area. Right now it's just a map with icons representing different types of events, and when clicked, provide more info. However I want to also provide a list of events as another way for the user to browse as a map with icons isn't very useful past seeing how many/what type of events are going on.

Would using a [navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlZ4u.png) make sense to display a list of the events? My problem is that they are typically used for switching tabs/screens rather than redirecting to information that is already on the screen. However putting the list on a separate screen entirely seems to break the flow. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what your proposal is - do you think about putting the events into the drawer, or do you think about putting navigation to a list of events into the drawer? If you add more detail, you'll probably get more responses.

Comment: Sorry, bit new to this exchange. What I meant was displaying all of the events in the drawer. I've only seen the navigation drawer used for switching tabs, but instead of that I want to display the list of events. I'm worried that taking this approach will throw users off. Hopefully that makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a slide up drawer? Kind of like this one from Google Maps?
http://cdn.pttrns.com/377/3927_f.jpg

If you could solve the issue with displaying the number of events in the icon, maybe that might make the issue of navigation drawers irrelevant?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about adding some interactivity to it?  Perhaps you can request a detail off the user (e.g. enter your postal / zip code), then show only the closest events to that postal code?

In fact if it's a mobile app you could just request that they share their location data and that way you reduce a step.  If it's not necessarily helpful to know where their current location is, the postal code solution works better.

I'm pretty against a navigation drawer if this is not the standard behaviour for a navigation drawer elsewhere in the app.

Also why not just switch between map view and list view offering both options, similar to Yelp / Urbanspoon / Zomato?

It's a little unclear without a diagram so apologies if that's vague but hope it helps a little.